# IntelliJ Idea can't find directory

Tags: java, intellij-idea, directory, filenotfoundexception

So, I recently switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ Idea, but for some reason when I run my java code, it can't find the directory where I store a file that I read in my program. I know that it works in Eclipse and when I export it as a jar file, so why doesn't it work in IntelliJ Idea? The specific error message is `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/Tyler/Google Drive/Java/Mac Workspace/maps/default.txt (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Hate to ask the obvious, but have you verified this file does exist? `/Users/Tyler/Google Drive/Java/Mac Workspace/maps/default.txt`

Comment: Yes, and even if it didn't exist, the program makes a new default.txt file.

Comment: Share your source code where you lookup this file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I figured out the problem. For some reason, IntelliJ set the working directory to the folder that contains the working directory. Instead of going to `/Users/Tyler/Google Drive/Java/Mac Workspace/Game/maps/default.txt` like it was supposed to, it was skipping the game folder and going to `/Users/Tyler/Google Drive/Java/Mac Workspace/maps/default.txt`. To fix this, go to "Run" > "Edit Configurations...", and add on to the field titled "Working Directory."

Comment: That's most likely happened because of some logic in the code. IntelliJ or Java don't just skip folders if not told so.

Comment: Actually, it was how I set up the project folder, since it's different from eclipse, but I didn't know that. The coding is fine.